# ESS produces "Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size"

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am trying ESS ([Emacs Speaks Statistics](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSpeaksStatistics)).

The problem is: Ctrl-P and the up-arrow are disabled on **any buffer** because of the following error:

> Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size

The trigger is the following line in .emacs.el

```
(require 'ess-site)
```

This line is needed [to load ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/readme.html#Installation). If I delete this line, then the problems does not happen, but, obviously, I can't use ESS.

Notes:

- "(setq max-lisp-eval-depth 10000)" does not solve the problem.
- "(setq max-specpdl-size 32000)" produces a different error:

  > Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
- When the above two settings are valid, then I get the error for max-lisp-eval-depth.
- This problem happens **before M-x R RET**. For example, it happens on the *scratch* buffer just after emacs starts.
- I have not found any other key with this problem. (So Ctrl-F and down-arrow are working, for example.)
- Deleting the *ESS* buffer does not solve the problem.
- The initial message on the *ESS* buffer is following. (I don't know, whether it is useful.)

  > [ess-site.el]: ess-customize-alist=nil 
  >   [ess-site.el *2*]: ess-customize-alist=nil 
  >   (S): ess-s-versions-create making M-x defuns for
  >
  > (R): ess-r-versions-create making M-x defuns for

Environment:

- emacs-ess-15.03.1-1.3.noarch
- emacs-24.3-17.2.10.x86_64
- R-base-3.1.1-2.1.9.x86_64
- openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: change the order of certain settings.

My .emacs.el has settings for smooth-scrolling (A)

```
(require 'smooth-scrolling)
(setq smooth-scroll-margin 5)
```

and for the initial file (B)

```
(find-file "~/init.org")
```

(A) should be loaded before (B). (B) was loaded before (A) in my previous .emacs.el and this causes the problem. (I do not know the precise reason for the error which I described in my question.)

Comment: If the loading file in (B) is .emacs.el, then the problem does not happen. So maybe an ogg-file should not be loaded before smooth-scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
(setq max-specpdl-size 32000)
```

`M-x describe-variable max-specpdl-size` for some info

I've had this problem with python-mode and rope, never with ESS though.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But unfortunately I get a different error: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'.

Comment: Did you try setting both variables to be larger?

Comment: Yes. (setq max-specpdl-size 64000) and (setq max-lisp-eval-depth 64000) kill emacs.

Comment: it might be something else in your `.emacs`.  You could try loading emacs without your .emacs: `emacs -q`.  Then evaluate `(require 'ess-site)` in scratch buffer with `C-j`.

Comment: Your are right. The error does not appear. I'll check my settings.

Comment: If I load my .emacs.el line by line from scratch buffer, then the error does not happen...

Comment: I don't know.  It sounds like there is some infinite recursion happening when you start emacs.  I would make a new file `.emacs` with only `(require 'ess-site)` in it. then do `emacs -q -l .emacs` and try to isolate the problem by building up the new `.emacs`.  In the file "ess-site.el" (`M-x locate-library ess-site`) there is a mention of infinite loops near the top.

Comment: I do not know the precise reason, but I have just solve the problem. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: I had the same problem when opening all files in a directory with `directory-files-recursively`. I was getting `File mode specification error: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`, so I doubled `max-specpdl-size`, and then I got `File mode specification error: (error Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’)`, so I doubled that too, and that fixed the problem.